# Arranging Div within div in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website structure with the help of bootstrap.

The problem is while arranging 3 div tags in 1 main div tag, they are not arranging side by side.
They themselves get arranged one below another.

```
<div class="col-md-12 collapse" style="border:1px solid blue;" id="part1">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid green;"><h5>Part 1.1</h5></div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid green;"><h5>Part 1.2</h5></div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid green;"><h5>Part 1.3</h5></div>
</div>
```

I want to arrange the 3 div tags one beside another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.col-md-4 {
display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amilapriyankara16/x4otc3ah/)

Comment: Thanks that Worked for me, but how can I increase the height of parent div tag with class "col-md-12"

Comment: This is a bad solution, you should not change those classes if you want to use bootstrap as intended.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap a `row` around your columns.

```
<div class="col-md-12 collapse border-solid border-blue" id="part1">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 border-solid border-green"><h5>Part 1.1</h5></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 border-solid border-green"><h5>Part 1.2</h5></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 border-solid border-green"><h5>Part 1.3</h5></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please do not use inline css, consider adding classes instead.

```
.border-solid {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.border-blue {
    border-color: blue;
}

.border-green {
    border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove Collapse

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid blue;" id="part1">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid green;"><h5>Part 1.1</h5></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid green;"><h5>Part 1.2</h5></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid green;"><h5>Part 1.3</h5></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div style="float:left; width: 20%">left<hr width="1" size="500">
</div>
<div style="float:none;">middle<hr width="1" size="500">
</div>
<div style="float:right;">right
</div>
```

Comment: No Explanation provided in the answer. Also no use of twitter bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.